# Postgresql calculate occupancy from a day based calendar table

Tags: postgresql

I have a `property_calendars` table in a postgreSQL database with a day-per-row structure for each property. Here's one month of sample data for one property as csv:

```
"id","property_id","status","price","currency","date","note","created_at","updated_at"
30053752,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-01",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053753,56,"booked",286,"GBP","2017-10-02",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053754,56,"booked",271,"GBP","2017-10-03",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053755,56,"booked",263,"GBP","2017-10-04",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053756,56,"booked",278,"GBP","2017-10-05",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053757,56,"booked",284,"GBP","2017-10-06",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053758,56,"booked",252,"GBP","2017-10-07",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053759,56,"booked",254,"GBP","2017-10-08",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053760,56,"available",247,"GBP","2017-10-09",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053761,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-10",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053762,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-11",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053763,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-12",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053764,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-13",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053765,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-14",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053766,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-15",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053767,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-16",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053768,56,"unavailable",170,"GBP","2017-10-17",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053769,56,"unavailable",170,"GBP","2017-10-18",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053770,56,"unavailable",170,"GBP","2017-10-19",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053771,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-20",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053772,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-21",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053773,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-22",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053774,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-23",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053775,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-24",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053776,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-25",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053777,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-26",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053778,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-27",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053779,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-28",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053780,56,"available",170,"GBP","2017-10-29",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053781,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-30",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
30053782,56,"booked",170,"GBP","2017-10-31",,"2018-04-19 04:04:48","2018-04-19 04:04:48"
```

What is the optimal way to query for occupancy for a given time period on a table like this? The formula to calculate occupancy in this context is: `x = (n - u) / n * 100` where

```
n = total nights 
u = unavailable nights
b = booked nights
x = occupancy
```

In the data above `26 / 31 * 100 = 87.83%` Occupancy for the month

Comment: Show sample data and expected results. Only in text format, no images please.

Comment: What is the formula to obtain occupancy? many don't know what occupancy means.

Comment: You really don't need the `E` prefix for any of those strings.

Comment: thanks @Dan and Kaushik- I have updated the question to be more explicit and include sample data

Comment: @eurotrash - pasted data instead

Comment: @KaushikNayak updated as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `COUNT` with a condition and then calculate the occupancy based on your formula (note: it seems that the correct formula is `b / (n - u) * 100` which gives `83.87%`).

```
WITH cte AS
(SELECT
  COUNT(*) n,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'booked' THEN 1 END) b,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'unavailable' THEN 1 END) u,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'available' THEN 1 END) a
FROM
  occupancy
WHERE
  "date" BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31')

SELECT 
  n, 
  b, 
  u, 
  a, 
  b * 100.0 / (n - u) occupancy -- the numerator is multiplied by a float 100.0 to avoid integer division
FROM cte
```

Since PostgreSQL 9.4 you can also use a `COUNT(*) FILTER (...)` clause:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'booked') b 
  ...
FROM occupancy
```

Comment: Thanks - actually the occupancy in this use case needs to be expressed as a % of available nights (total nights - unavailable nights)

Comment: OK I've updated the formula to `b * 100.0 / (n - u)`. I hope it's correct.

Comment: It's a great solution. Thanks.